# Invalid Registration error in quickblox android 2.5.2

Tags: android, quickblox

Sending push from QB Admin in android

1. I got subscribe to push.
2. Push sender is successful
3. Receiver is unable to get the push notification .

> ERROR : Invalid Registration

In earlier version of quickblox , I did not added any gcm registration ID. But in 2.5.2, even I added gcm registration ID, still not working.

Please guide me in this.

Comment: Add some code. And precise the problem, What is not working?

Comment: Hi Laur, Tell your email, so that i can share my code, here i'm unable to code as i'm new user, with low credits. you can mail me cloudeyetech@gmail.com thank you.

Comment: Where do you receive this error?

Comment: While i'm sending from QB Admin, Push Notification , in Queue section, status showing as sent, while I click 'message log' and in 'download detail log', it showing as ' Invalid Registration"

Comment: Hello any one got the solution for the same?
As i am also facing the same issue.